# Which LOL champion has the lowest basic attack at level 18?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which League of Legends champion has the lowest basic attack damage at level 18? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Orianna currently has the lowest base attack damage at level 18.

Source: [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions%27_attack_damage)

For those interested, here are a [list of all the champion statistics.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Lists_of_champion_stats)

Comment: answered in 1:30 minutes impressive, haha.

Comment: Thanks for that link! i didn't know lol's wiki had that

Comment: No problem, I use it for a lot of my League questions.

Comment: However, keep in mind that both Orianna and Lulu (the two lowest AD at 18) have significant attack modifiers as their passive. Orianna, for example, has a +50 +15% of her AP per hit as magic damage. The lowest damage per autoattack in a real-life situation will be Fiddlesticks.